# How to implementing a application with Linux DMA

Tags: linux, drivers, dma

As far as I know, Linux provides common DMA framework for various DMA engine and a device driver for DMA engine have to be implemented based on the the framework.

Is the framework provide any system calls or mechanism for user application such as: `open()`, `ioctl()`? Or do developers have to implement the file-operations for user space?

Comment: Start with this: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=dma+in+linux+userspace